# How to maintain the order of an existing dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I created a dictionary, and later I'd like in insert it's values to a list. I know that lists keep their order, but I think that dictionaries are not. I know there is OrderedDict, but from what I understand it keeps the order upon addition to the dictionary. Here, I have already the complete dictionary, without adding to it.

I'm using python 3.6

My script is:

```
dirs_dictionary = {"user_dir_treatment":"/home/dataset_1/treatment",
                           "user_dir_control":"/home/dataset_1/control"}

empty_list = []

for key, value in dirs_dictionary.items():
    empty_list.append(dirs_dictionary[key])
```

So eventually, I'd like that the list will contain the values in the same order as they are in the dictionary, meaning that the first item in the list is `"/home/dataset_1/treatment"`, and the second is `"/home/dataset_1/control"`.

How do I maintain the order of my dictionary?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? The ordering behaviour of dictionaries is different in different versions.

Comment: I'm using python version 3.6.4

Comment: This question makes no sense. The dict won't change its order if you don't modify it, so what's the problem? You have to do _absolutely nothing_ to maintain its order. If you're planning to modify the dict though, then use an OrderedDict.

Comment: you can use OrderedDict

Comment: Use python 3.7, you will have dict key ordering perserved ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3.6, dictionaries are ordered internally, but this is considered an *implementation detail* which should not be relied upon.

In Python 3.7, dictionaries are ordered.

Therefore, you have 2 options:

**Use the implementation detail at your risk**

You can use `list(d)` to retrieve the keys of the dictionary maintaining insertion order.

```
dirs_dictionary = {"user_dir_treatment":"/home/dataset_1/treatment",
                   "user_dir_control":"/home/dataset_1/control"}

empty_list = list(dirs_dictionary)

print(empty_list)

# ['user_dir_treatment', 'user_dir_control']
```

**Use OrderedDict**

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dirs_dictionary = OrderedDict([("user_dir_treatment", "/home/dataset_1/treatment"),
                               ("user_dir_control", "/home/dataset_1/control")]

empty_list = list(dirs_dictionary)

print(empty_list)

# ['user_dir_treatment', 'user_dir_control']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just to make sure I understand, The second option is the safest to keep the order, but in the first option it is not sure that the order will be maintained?

Comment: Sorry, just have to repeat my wording. Dictionaries are internally ordered in 3.6 [read, "it works"], but it is considered an *implementation detail* [i.e. you shouldn't use this fact in  your logic]. The second way is the "proper" method in 3.6.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!