# loop over list and dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary and a list.
I want for the keys that have the same value, the program adds the int in the list that have the same positions as the keys in the dictionary.

So I want that the code make: `addition = [30+5, 40+0, 10]`
So I want this output: `addition = [35,40,10]`

```
addition = []  
dic = {"a": 0, "b":1, "c": 1, "d": 0, "e": 2}
list = [30,40,0,5,10]
```

And I really don't know how to make that. I think with a for loop perhaps.

PS: I know it's bad to call a list a list but it's for the comprehension.

Thank you

Comment: But dict elements don't have positions. Do you want to sort the keys alphabetically?

Comment: I know but I don't want to sort the dictionary but I though to convert the list to a dictionary so list = {"a":30, "b":40, "c":0, "d":5, "e":2} and then add the value that are the same in dic but from list. So addition = [a+d, b+c, e]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this option, working for Python 3.6+:

```
addition = []  
dic = {"apple": 0, "coke":1, "zebra": 1, "France": 0, "e": 2}
mlist = [30,40,0,5,10]

dic_map={}
for i, (k,v) in enumerate(dic.items()):
  dic_map.setdefault(v, set()).add(i)

for k, v in dic_map.items():
  addition.append(sum([x for i, x in enumerate(mlist) if i in v ]))

print(addition)
#=> [35, 40, 10]
```

For knowing why it works only for Python 3.6+ (reliable?), see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49752234/5239030

Comment: This only works for Python 3.6+

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, good point, thank you. I made an edit.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are linking the list and dict by the *index of the letter in the alphabet*, you can do:

```
from itertools import groupby
from string import ascii_lowercase
from operator import itemgetter

dic = {"a": 0, "b":1, "c": 1, "d": 0, "e": 2}
lst = [30, 40, 0, 5, 10]

res = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(dic.items(), key=itemgetter(1)), itemgetter(1))]
addition = [sum(lst[ascii_lowercase.index(x)] for x, _ in sublist) for sublist in res]
```

which results in

```
print(addition)  # -> [35, 40, 10]
```

---

On the comments you say that you do not want to sort the dictionary. Well that's good because you cannot do that anyway. But you have to sort the `dict.items()` in order to group them. If that is a problem, you have to reconsider your needs because I do not see another way..

Comment: that's good but if my dic is like this: dic = {"apple": 0, "coke":1, "zebra": 1, "France": 0, "e": 2}, I cannot use ascii

Comment: @Waterploof If your dict is like this how do you want to *link* `"apple"` to `30`? **Dicts are not ordered**

Comment: I though to convert  dic = {"apple": 0, "coke":1, "zebra": 1, "France": 0, "e": 2} to dic = {"0": 0, "1":1, "2": 1, "3": 0, "4": 2}

Comment: @Waterploof And how do you convert `"apple"` to `"0"`. There is no order in dicts; they are just presented as if there were. What python version are you using?